# Android Mediaplayer @ Samsung S i9000

Tags: android, stream, media-player, freeze

i coded an app, which called the android mediaplayer to play an audiostream (by URL). In the emulator (Android 2.2) everything works fine (The App plays the stream). When I install the App on my HTC Desire (Android 2.2) it works fine.
This week a friend installed the app on his Samsung S i9000 (Android 2.2) and it didn´t work. The app just freezes and the user is called to wait or to abort when mediaplayer.start(); is called.
When the app initialises the mediaplayer is constructed (by standard constructor), but on the i9000 you are changing the the call volume, not the media volume if you push the buttons.
Any ideas? :)

Edit: When i call a mp3-file instead of the stream the i9000 plays it... confusing...

Comment: @leppie: Why? It's a perfectly valid question about Android programming.

Comment: @skaffman: Sorry, I missed the 'coded' part :) Vote reverted.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/mynpr/

hi, you can adapt this code and it will work. I have the same issue in my LG P970, and ive solved with this player-

Bassically it has 2 stream method, the first its the "normal" one, wich doesn't work on our devices :(

The second method is about downloading part of the stream to a buffer, save it in SDcard, and then play it, and this works on all devices.